# Calling super() inside a class' classmethod to get at the metaclass method

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

*Just when I though I understood metaclasses...*

**Disclaimer**: I have looked around for an answer before posting, but most of the answers I have found are about calling `super()` to get at another `@classmethod` in the MRO (no metaclass involved) or, surprisingly, a lot of them were about trying to do something in `metaclass.__new__` or `metaclass.__call__` which meant the class wasn't fully created yet. I'm pretty sure (let's say 97%) that this is not one of those problems.

**Environment**: Python 3.7.2

**The problem**:
I have a metaclass `FooMeta` that defines a method `get_foo(cls)`, a class `Foo` that is built from that metaclass (so an instance of `FooMeta`) and has a `@classmethod` `get_bar(cls)`. Then another class `Foo2` that inherits from `Foo`. In `Foo2`, I subclass `get_foo` by declaring it a `@classmethod` and calling `super()`. This fails miserably...

i.e. with this code

```py
class FooMeta(type):
    def get_foo(cls):
        return 5


class Foo(metaclass=FooMeta):
    @classmethod
    def get_bar(cls):
        return 3


print(Foo.get_foo)
# >>> <bound method FooMeta.get_foo of <class '__main__.Foo'>>
print(Foo.get_bar)
# >>> <bound method Foo.get_bar of <class '__main__.Foo'>>


class Foo2(Foo):
    @classmethod
    def get_foo(cls):
        print(cls.__mro__)
        # >>> (<class '__main__.Foo2'>, <class '__main__.Foo'>, <class 'object'>)
        return super().get_foo()

    @classmethod
    def get_bar(cls):
        return super().get_bar()


print(Foo2().get_bar())
# >>> 3
print(Foo2().get_foo())
# >>> AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'get_foo'
```

**The question**:
So with my class being an instance of the metaclass, and having verified that both class methods exist on the class `Foo`, why aren't both calls to the `super().get_***()` working inside `Foo2`? **What am I not understanding about metaclasses or `super()` that's preventing me from finding these results logical?**

EDIT: Further testing shows that the methods on `Foo2` being class methods or instance methods doesn't change the result.

EDIT 2: Thanks to @chepner's answer, I think the problem was that `super()` was returning a super object representing `Foo` (this is verified with `super().__thisclass__`) and I was expecting `super().get_foo()` to behave (maybe even to call) `get_attr(Foo, 'get_foo')` behind the scene. It seems that it isn't... I'm still wondering why, but it is getting clearer :)

Comment: The most direct way will be `return FooMeta.get_foo(cls) + 1`, but it begs the question - metaclasses are for customizing creation of the class.  You're not doing that.  So, *why are you using a metaclass*?  `super` is more about traversing the MRO (parent or sibling classes when using inheritance) so I'm not really sure why you're trying to use it to get at a metaclass method in the first place, these are quite unrelated concerns.

Comment: @wim I have made the code as simple as possible to illustrate the problem. Obviously there's a thousand different and simpler ways to write _this_ logic without metaclasses, but that is not my question (TBH, the actual code that led me to ask myself and SO this question is already pushed in a simpler form, but still with a mcs, because it was needed). My question is more theoretical than practical (cf. the last sentence of the original post). Through this, I'm trying to have a better understanding of the way python works.

Comment: The more I test, the more I think it is my understanding of the way super() works that is at fault...

Comment: Your understanding seems OK so far, but I'm not clear on why would you expect `super(FooMeta, Foo)` to proxy to an existing `get_foo` method at all? Because, in absence of anything else in the inheritance chain, the "next method" here would just be attempting a method resolution on `type`.  If you wanted to access the metaclass `get_foo` method, you just use `FooMeta.get_foo` directly.

Comment: @wim I have updated the example and the question. I have been doing more tests on my side so, short of finding an actual answer, I do hope I've managed to narrow the question to its essentials.

Comment: I don't have an actual answer, but I'll point out as interesting (if nothing else) that `get_foo` does not appear in the return value of `dir(Foo)`. (This is really just another indication that `super().get_foo` will fail, rather than an explanation of *why* it will fail).

Comment: @chepner: That's really just because `dir` is designed for interactive convenience over consistency. Quoting the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir): "Note: Because dir() is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases. For example, metaclass attributes are not in the result list when the argument is a class."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Foo` may have a `get_foo` method, but `super` isn't designed to check what attributes a superclass has. `super` cares about what attributes *originate* in a superclass.

---

To understand `super`'s design, consider the following multiple inheritance hierarchy:

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    def f(cls):
        return 1
class B(A):
    pass
class C(A):
    @classmethod
    def f(cls):
        return 2
class D(B, C):
    @classmethod
    def f(cls):
        return super().f() + 1
```

A, B, C, and D all have an `f` classmethod, but B's `f` is inherited from A. D's method resolution order, the sequence of classes checked for attribute lookup, goes `(D, B, C, A, object)`.

`super().f() + 1` searches the MRO of `cls` for an `f` implementation. The one it should find is `C.f`, but B has an inherited `f` implementation, and B is before C in the MRO. If `super` were to pick up `B.f`, this would break `C`'s attempt to override `f`, in a situation commonly referred to as the "diamond problem".

Instead of looking at what attributes B has, `super` looks directly in B's `__dict__`, so it only considers attributes actually provided by `B` instead of by `B`'s superclasses or metaclasses.

---

Now, back to your `get_foo`/`get_bar` situation. `get_bar` comes from `Foo` itself, so `super().get_bar()` finds `Foo.get_bar`. However, `get_foo` is provided not by `Foo`, but by the `FooMeta` metaclass, and there is no entry for `get_foo` in `Foo.__dict__`. Thus, `super().get_foo()` finds nothing.

Comment: Thank you !!! This was the "ahaah!" moment for me :) Your example with multiple inheritance shows quite clearly *why* `super().get_foo()` can't simply do a `getattr(Foo, 'get_foo')` behind the scene. Thank you :)

Comment: This is a great answer. I was looking into the CPython source code to see if the implementation of `super` gave any explanation for why it works the way it does (nope). If you're curious, you can find the C code for what is effectively `super.__getattribute__` [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/17269090940aa20f6079a6b9f27ae319f8cdae14/Objects/typeobject.c#L7739).

Answer (score 0):

## Note 1

Just to be clear:

- `Foo` does ***not*** inherit from `FooMeta`.
- `FooMeta` is ***not*** a super-class of `Foo`

`super` will not work.

## Note 2

Now that note (1) is out of the way, if you want to access a metaclass method from inside of a method of an instance of the metaclass, you can do it like this:

```
class FooMeta(type):
    _foo = 5

    def get_foo(cls):
        print("`get_foo` from `FooMeta` was called!")

    class Foo(metaclass=FooMeta):

        @classmethod
        def bar(Foo):
            FooMeta = type(Foo)
            FooMeta_dot_getfoo = FooMeta.get_foo
            FooMeta_dot_getfoo(Foo)

        def baz(self):
            Foo = type(self)
            FooMeta = type(Foo)
            FooMeta_dot_getfoo = FooMeta.get_foo
            FooMeta_dot_getfoo(Foo)

    Foo.bar()
    foo = Foo()
    foo.baz()
```

The output is:

```
`get_foo` from `FooMeta` was called!
`get_foo` from `FooMeta` was called!
```

## Note 3

If you have a classmethod with the same name as a method in the metaclass, why does the metaclass method ***NOT*** get called? Consider the following code:

```
class FooMeta(type):
    def get_foo(cls):
        print("META!")

class Foo(metaclass=FooMeta):
    @classmethod
    def get_foo(cls):
        print("NOT META!")

Foo.get_foo()
```

The output is `NOT META!` In the following discussion, assume that:

- `foo` is instance of `Foo`
- `Foo` is instance of `FooMeta`

For the first time in this post, I will have pseudo code, not python. Don't try to run the following. `__getattribute__` sorta looks like the following:

```
class FooMeta(type):
    def get_foo(Foo):
        print("META!")

class Foo(metaclass=FooMeta):
    @classmethod
    def get_foo(Foo):
        print("NOT META!")

    def __getattribute__(foo, the string "get_foo"):
        try:
            attribute = "get_foo" from instance foo
        except AttributeError:
            attribute = "get_foo" from class Foo

        # Begin code for handling "descriptors"
        if hasattr(attribute, '__get__'):
            attr = attribute.__get__(None, Foo)
        # End code for handling "descriptors"

        return attribute

foo = Foo()
foo.get_foo() # prints "NOT META!"

get_foo = Foo.__getattribute__(foo, "get_foo")
get_foo.__call__()
```

You can actually ignore the stuff which says, "`code for handling "descriptors"`." I only included that for completeness.

Note that nowhere does `__getattribute__` say, "get `get_foo` from the meta class."

1. First, We try to get `get_foo` from the instance. Maybe `get_foo` is a member variable. Maybe one instance has `get_foo = 1` and another instance has `get_foo = 5` The computer does not know. The computer is stupid.
2. The computer realizes that the instance doesn't have a member variable named `get_foo`. It then says, "ah ha! I bet that `get_foo` belongs to the CLASS." So, it looks there, and lo-and-behold, there it is: `Foo` has an attribute named `get_foo`. `FooMeta` also has an attribute called `get_foo`, but who cares about that.

Something to focus on is that:

- `Foo` has an attribute named `get_foo`
- `MetaFoo` has an attribute named `get_foo`

They ***both*** have attributes named `get_foo`, but `Foo` and `MetaFoo` are different objects. It's not as if the two `get_foo`s are shared. I can have `obj1.x = 1` and `obj2.x = 99`. No problem.

`FooMeta` has its own `__getattribute__` method. Before I talked about `Foo.__getattribute__`, but now let's talk about the **MeTa** `__getattribute__`

```
class FooMeta(type):
    def get_foo(Foo):
        print("META!")

    def __getattribute__(Foo, the string "get_foo"):
        try:                                            # LINE 1
            attribute = "get_foo" from class Foo        # LINE 2
        except AttributeError:                          # LINE 3
            attribute = "get_foo" from class FooMeta    # LINE 4
                                                        # LINE 5
        # Begin code for handling "descriptors"
        if hasattr(attribute, '__get__'):
            attr = attribute.__get__(None, Foo)
        # End code for handling "descriptors"

        return attribute

class Foo(metaclass=FooMeta):
    @classmethod
    def get_foo(Foo):
        print("NOT META!")

Foo.get_foo()

get_foo = FooMeta.__getattribute__(Foo, "get_foo")
get_foo.__call__()
```

The order of events:

- Lines 1 and 2 happen
- Lines 3, 4, & 5 do **not** happen
- You can ignore the stuff about descriptors, because none of the different `get_foo`s in this problem have a `__get__` method

Okay now! Why only lines 1 & 2? Because you made a `@classmethod` silly! We check `Foo` to see if it has a `get_foo` and it does! Why check for class attributes if we find an instance attribute first? We always check to see if an attribute belong to the instance (`Foo`) ***first-and-foremost*** before checking if maybe there happens to be only one copy of a static member variable belonging to the class (`FooMeta`) and shared by all of the instances.

Note that if Foo does not have a `get_foo` then `FooMeta.__getattribute__(Foo, "get_foo")` will return `get_foo` from the metaclass because the first attempt (getting it from the instance) failed. You kinda blocked that option out by giving the instance something of the same name as the class's static member variable.

```
class K:

    im_supposed_to_be_shared = 1

    def __init__(self, x):
        # NOPE!
        self.im_supposed_to_be_shared = x
        # maybe try type(self)

obj1 = K(14)
obj2 = K(29)
print(obj1.im_supposed_to_be_shared)
print(obj2.im_supposed_to_be_shared)
print(K.im_supposed_to_be_shared)
```

Prints:

```
14
29
1
```

does ***NOT*** print:

```
29
29
29
```

Note that if you want to set a static class member variable, `instance.mem_var = 5` is a very **ⱽᵉᴿʸ** bad idea. You will give the `instance` a new member variable, and the class static (shared) member variable will be shadowed. You can fix that with something like this:

```
def __setattr__(self, attr_name, attr_val):
    if hasattr(type(self), attr_name):
        setattr(type(self), attr_name, attr_val)
    else:
        super_class = inspect.getmro(type(self))[1]
        super_class.__setattr__(self, attr_name, attr_val)
```

Then your lil' compy will print:

```
29
29
29
```

## Note 4

```
class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def funky(cls):
        pass
```

is **NOT** `MetaClass.funky = funky`. Instead, it's:

```
def funky(cls)
   pass
Funky = classmethod (funky)
```

... which is almost the same as:

```
def funky(cls):
     pass
funky = lambda self, *args, **kwargs: funky(type(self), *args, **kwargs)
```

The moral of note 4s story is that `classmethod` `funky` is an attribute of `Foo` and not an attribute of `FooMeta`

Comment: You don't seem to have addressed `super` anywhere in this post, which is kind of strange for an answer posted on a question about `super`.

Comment: @user2357112 You can't use `super` to get the meta-class because a class does not inherit from a meta-class. In my answer, I explain that you can use `type(class)` instead of `super()`

Comment: As for your attribute-access pseudo-code on note 3 - note that descriptors featuring a `__set__` or `__delete__`  (data descriptors) have priority, even if an attribute exists in the instance's `__dict__` as well.

Answer (score 0):

`get_foo` is not an attribute of `Foo`, but rather an attribute of `type(Foo)`:

```
>>> 'get_foo' in Foo.__dict__
False
>>> 'get_foo' in type(Foo).__dict__
True
```

So while `Foo.get_foo` will resolve to `type(Foo).get_foo`, `super().get_foo` does not because the proxy returned by `super()` is similar to `Foo`, but is not `Foo` itself.

Comment: This answer, I think, requires a deeper dive into the descriptor protocol, but I don't have the time to do so.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is in fact a step closer to answering the question. It could just be that `get_attr` on a super object is not the same as `get_attr` on the object represented by `super_object.__thisclass__`. I still find the asymmetry troubling (they are both methods of Foo after all).

Comment: @chepner There are not descriptors here with `__get__` and `__set__`. `@classmethod` is a decorator, not a descriptor.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon: The objects returned by the `classmethod` decorator are, in fact, descriptors. They could not perform their functionality without being descriptors.

Comment: The whole *purpose* of the `classmethod` type is to provide an object with a different implementation of `__get__`.

Answer (score 0):

`obj.attr` calls `type(obj).__getattribute__(obj, 'attr')`, that is

- a) `object.__getattribute__(obj, 'attr')`, which looks up `'attr'` in `obj` itself, as well as in the class of `obj` and its parents; or
- b) `type.__getattribute__(obj, 'attr')` if `obj` is a `type` instance, which looks up `'attr'` in `obj` itself and its parents, as well as in the class of `obj` and its parents; or
- c) `super.__getattribute__(obj, 'attr')` if `obj` is a `super` instance,

  - c.1) which looks up `'attr'` in the class of `instance` and its parents past `cls`, if `obj` is `super(cls, instance)`, or
  - c.2) which looks up `'attr'` in `subclass` itself and its parents past `cls`, if `obj` is `super(cls, subclass)`.

When you call `super().get_foo()` in the class method `Foo2.get_foo`, which is equivalent to calling `super(Foo2, cls).get_foo()`, you are in case c.2), i.e. you are looking up `'get_foo'` in `cls` itself and its parents past `Foo2`, i.e. you are looking up `'get_foo'` in `Foo`. That is why the call fails.

You expect the call `super().get_foo()` in the class method `Foo2.get_foo` to succeed because you think it is equivalent to the call `Foo.get_foo()` which is in case b), i.e. you think you are looking up `'get_foo'` in `cls` itself and its parents, **as well as in the class of `Foo` (`FooMeta`) and its parents**.